# How to monitory avaliable RAM via azure monitor

Tags: azure, ram

I wanted to create a chart showing per cent of memory available

the issue is the perf table table has %committed bytes in use but this does not include cashed byets show is not a true reflection

After some googling I found

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/monitor-virtual-machine-alerts

Which give you a working solution

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms"
| where Namespace == "Memory" and Name == "AvailableMB"

| extend TotalMemory = toreal(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/memorySizeMB"]) | extend AvailableMemoryPercentage = (toreal(Val) / TotalMemory) * 100.0
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(AvailableMemoryPercentage) by bin(TimeGenerated, 15m), Computer, _ResourceId
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

This gives you an accurate memory of being consumed

I did not come up with this solution but I wanted to share it on here

Answer (score 0):

As I said above the solution is

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms"
| where Namespace == "Memory" and Name == "AvailableMB"

| extend TotalMemory = toreal(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/memorySizeMB"]) | extend AvailableMemoryPercentage = (toreal(Val) / TotalMemory) * 100.0
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(AvailableMemoryPercentage) by bin(TimeGenerated, 15m), Computer, _ResourceId
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

and is wholly based on After some googling I found

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/monitor-virtual-machine-alerts